# What is the commandment about women veil on working place?

Tags: practical-islam, women, work

As a student and working lady we have to interact with a number of people even men in our everyday routine. If a women veil but cannot wear gloves for whole day because of it's working situation. As we interact with strangers (Non-Mehrams) and also communicate with them. What is the Islam says about these situations? Is it right for a Muslim women?

Comment: Why would you wear gloves and for what?

Comment: The purpose of wearing gloves is to cover your hands(body) as being a Muslim women.

Comment: Why the hands are not 'awrah? Consider editing the question title as it sounds too broad!

Comment: There is difference on whether the face and hands are part of the 'awrah for a woman. I either case the commandment about veils and gloves is the same wherever Muslim women are with strangers (non-Mahrams), be it at a workplace or otherwise.

Comment: Everything of a women is Awrah. Sometimes even a sweet voice can cause fitnah.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of debate among jurists as to whether the ruling on hijab covers the face and hands even from the wrists down or not. Many believe that covering these two (face and shroud) is an exception to the ruling on hijab, while Some fatwas are obligatory to cover, or at least they are cautious, of course, those who do not consider it obligatory to cover the two also bind it in such a way that it does not become a source of corruption and deviation, otherwise it is obligatory. (Sample Interpretation; Volume 14; Page 449.)

In verse 31 of Surah Noor, there is evidence of this exception and confirmation of the first statement, such as "They should not reveal their adornment except what is naturally apparent." Adornment is a clear reason why it is not necessary to cover the face and shroud. (Sample Interpretation; Volume 14; Pages 439 and 450.)

It is necessary to cover your hands as a hijab when your hands are adorned. That means decorating your nails, or painting henna like the Indians and Pakistanis, or wearing attractive rings that attract the attention of others. Otherwise there is no need to cover the hands.

Reference: https://www.mehrnews.com/news/3711072